# NOOP where in JOOQ

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

I'm providing a method that allow multiple filtering options when querying against the `books` table. The first portion of the query either searches over all books, or only those owned by the current user.

```
 val allBookQuery = if(searchParameters.isOnShelf == true) {
    val context = environment.getContext<AuthorizedContext>()
    context?.currentUser ?: throw GraphQLException("No Current User Authenticated")
    val userUUID = UUID.fromString(context.currentUser.uuid)

    select.from(BOOKS, USER_BOOKS, USERS)
    .where(USERS.UUID.eq(userUUID))
    .and(USERS.ID.eq(USER_BOOKS.USER_ID))
    .and(USER_BOOKS.BOOK_ID.eq(BOOKS.ID))
    .and(BOOKS.IS_ARCHIVED.eq(false))
} else {
    select.from(BOOKS).where(true)
}
```

The `.where(true)` expression is used to keep the type of `allBookQuery` consistent, so that later I can append other conditions without checking for types.

```
val filteredBooksQuery = if (searchParameters.bookIds != null) {
    allBookQuery.and(BOOKS.ID.`in`(searchParameters.bookIds))
} else {
    allBookQuery
}

val finalQuery = if (searchParameters.isAcademic == true) {
    filteredBooksQuery.and(BOOKS.IS_ACADEMIC.eq((true)))
} else {
    filteredBooksQuery
}
```

Unfortunately the `where(Boolean)` method has been deprecated. So while this works for now, I'd like to replace this with a NOOP operation that isn't deprecated.

Comment: Maybe you could use the "dynamic SQL" approach of jOOQ (https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/)?

Comment: I'll be looking at this as a longer term refactoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `where(true)` try `where(trueCondition())` (`trueCondition()` is a static method of `DSL`).

Note that `where(trueCondition())` assumes that you will add additional predicates to your `allBookQuery` using `and(Condition)` and would of course be wrong if you were to use `or(Condition)`. To be independent of this it is thus even better to use `where(noCondition())`, for which no SQL is rendered.